# JAXB marshalling failed: "null" error when running an application on websphere. Same application runs fine on Tomcat

Tags: java, jaxb, websphere, marshalling

I have a web application containing a servlet which runs fine on Apache Tomcat. However, when I deploy the war file on Websphere Developer Edition 8, I get the following error when the servlet gets executed.

```
  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught 
service() exception root cause DfsDownloadServiceServlet: javax.servlet.ServletException:
com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.ServiceInvocationRuntimeException:
com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.ServiceInvocationRuntimeException: JAXB marshalling failed: 
"null". at com.company.dfs.download.DfsDownloadServiceServlet.doPost(DfsDownloadServiceServlet.java:158)
```

Can anyone give any pointers as to why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like one of 2 possibilities. 1) A bug in the container (not terribly likely, but possible). 2) Some setup or config that is missing on one versus the other (for instance a JNDI entry, JDBC entry, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there are the same libraries in different versions in your warfile or maybe provided by websphere.

I had the problem as well, the war file would run on tomcat without problems, but on websphere it didnt run.

I searched and found some libraries which were there twice in different versions. Looks like the classloader of Tomcat and Websphere have different loading orders.

Maybe that solves your problem